# How to map JSON Object to array with keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

There's about million questions (and answers) out there on this topic, but none of them are doing what I need to do. I have a JSON object where the value for each key is an object. I want to convert this to an array and maintain the top level keys.

```
{
  "someKey1": {
    active: true,
    name: "foo"
  },
  "someKey2": {
    active: false,
    name: "bar"
  }
}
```

If I use Object.keys() I get the top level keys, but not their values. If I use Object.values() I get an array with all the values, but not their keys. I'm trying to use keys and map, but am only getting the values returned:

```
const data = {
  "someKey1": {
    active: true,
    name: "foo"
  },
  "someKey2": {
    active: false,
    name: "bar"
  }
}
const items = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
    return data[key];
});

// returns [{active: true, name: foo},{active: false, name: bar}]
```

Is there a way to get both? I want to get an array I can iterate over that looks something like this:

```
[{
    key: someKey1,
    active: true,
    name: "foo"
},
{
    key: someKey2,
    active: true,
    name: "foo"
}]

OR

[
"someKey1": {
    active: true,
    name: "foo"
},
"someKey2": {
    active: false,
    name: "bar"
}
]
```

Comment: You mean [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?

Comment: Object.entries() would just give me an array of arrays containing the keys and values. I want to get to one array or objects.

Comment: Ok well the second example output you provided wouldn't be possible, since arrays can't have keys... but if you want to produce the first example (with the keys as strings), either answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going in the right direction, if you want to add the "key" property you have to map the properties manually and for the second option since you don't need the "key" property it can be done a little bit more elegantly:

For the first option:

```
Object.keys(data).map(v => ({
    key: v,
    ...data[v]
}));
```

For the second option even simpler:

```
Object.keys(data).map(v => ({[v]: {...data[v]}}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily map your data to a new object:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ ...data[key], "key": key }));
```